# Airflow task setup with execution date

Tags: airflow

I want to customize the task to be weekday dependent in the dag file. It seems the airflow macros like `{{ next_execution_date }}` are not directly available in the python dag file. This is my dag definition:

```
RG_TASKS = {
    'asia': {
        'start_date': pendulum.datetime.(2021,1,1,16,0,tzinfo='Asia/Tokyo'),
        'tz': 'Asia/Tokyo',
        'files': [
            '/path/%Y%m%d/asia_file1.%Y%m%d.csv',
            '/path/%Y%m%d/asia_file2.%Y%m%d.csv',
            ...], },
    'euro': {
        'start_date': pendulum.datetime.(2021,1,1,16,0,tzinfo='Europe/London'),
        'tz': 'Europe/London',
        'files': [
            '/path/%Y%m%d/euro_file1.%Y%m%d.csv',
            '/path/%Y%m%d/euro_file2.%Y%m%d.csv',
            ...], },
}

dag = DAG(..., start_date=pendulum.datetime.(2021,1,1,16,0,tzinfo='Asia/Tokyo'),
    schedule='00 16 * * 0-6')

for rg, t in RG_TASKS.items():
    tz = t['tz']
    h = t['start_date'].hour
    m = t['start_date'].minute
    target_time = f'{{{{ next_execution_date.replace(tzinfo="{tz}", hour={h}, minute={m}) }}}}'
    time_sensor = DateTimeSensor(dag=dag, task_id=f'wait_for_{rg}', tartget_time=target_time)
    bash_task = BashOperator(dag=dag, task_id='load_{rg}', trigger_rule='all_success', depends_on_past=True, bash_command=...)
    for fname in t['files']:
        fpath = f'{{{{ next_execution_date.strftime("{fname}") }}}}'
        task_id = os.path.basename(fname).split('.')[0]
        file_sensor = FileSensor(dag=dag, task_id=task_id, filepath=fpath, ...)
        file_sensor.set_upstream(time_sensor)
        file_sensor.set_downstream(bash_task)
```

The above works, and the bash_task will be triggered if all files are available, and it is set depend_on_past=True. However, the files have slightly different schedule. `{rg}_file1` will be available 6 days/week, except Saturday, while the rest are available 7 days a week.

One option is to create 2 dags, one scheduled to run Sun-Fri, while the other is scheduled to run Sat only. But with this option, the depends_on_past=True is broken on Saturday.

Is there any better way to keep depends_on_past=True 7 days/week? Ideally in the files loop, I could do sth like:

```
    for fname in t['files']:
        dt = ...
        if dt.weekday()==5 and task_id==f'{rg}_file1':
            continue
```

Answer (score 1):

Generally I think it's better to accomplish things in a single task when it is easy enough to do, and in this case it seem to me you can.

I'm not entirely sure why you are using a datetime sensor, but it does not seem necessary.  As far as I can tell, you just want your process to run every day (ideally after the file is there) and skip once per week.

I think we can do away with file sensor too.

#### Option 1: everything in bash

Check for existence in your bash script and fail (with retries) if missing.  Just return non-zero exit code when file missing.

Then in your bash script you could silently do nothing on the skip day.

On skip days, your bash task will be green even though it did nothing.

#### Option 2: subclass bash operator

Subclass BashOperator and add a `skip_day` parameter.  Then your execute is like this:

```py
def execute(self, context):
    next_execution_date = context['next_execution_date']
    if next_execution_date.day_of_week == self.skip_day:
        raise AirflowSkipException(f'we skip on day {self.skip_day}')
    super().execute(context)
```

With this option your bash script still needs to fail if file missing, but doesn't need to deal with the skip logic.  And you'll be able to see that the task skipped in the UI.

Either way, no sensors.

#### Other note

You can simplify your filename templating.

```py
files=[
'/path/{{ next_ds_nodash }}/euro_file2.{{ next_ds_nodash }}.csv',
...
]
```

Then you don't need to mess with `strftime`.

Comment: The actual path/file is more complex than %Y%m%d, that's why the strftime. The DateTimeSensor is added as I am under the impression FileSensor may not be efficient enough. We don't want the FileSensor to continuously ping dozens of files early, if we know they will be available later in the day based on local region's time zone.

Comment: The files are from vendor, and comes in multiple batches by region. In most cases, they arrive on time. But occasionally they may be late and we need to notified which file is late. The python data loading script (which bash script calls) is aware of the availability of files on which day, and it will handle it properly if all files on that day are available.

Comment: fundamentally, the answer i give is, "use `AirflowSkipException`".  it's the airflow analog to `continue` in your loop example.